# switching from Texlive 2015 to Texlive 2016

Tags: package-management, latex

I am running TeXLive 2015 on 16.04 (32 bit), installed manually, according to the instructions at

https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

I have been trying to upgrade to TeXLive 2016. I understand I can proceed as before, resulting in the directory /usr/local/texlive/2016, etc., but I would like to install via apt instead.

The issue is: when I finish apt-get installing texlive-full (using the [jonathonf ppa repository](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016)) I do not know how to get Ubuntu to switch to running pdflatex through 2016 instead of the old 2015.

The command tex -v still returns Tex Live 2015.

Comment: You shouldn't mix installation methods like you did. APT doesn't know about the old installation.

Comment: I understand; but I was wondering what the fastest way to move over to '16 is. Given that I do currently have both installations on my system, is there an expeditious way of getting the system to use the APT-installed version at compilation?

Comment: Give us the result of update-alternatives --list pdflatex

Comment: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for pdflatex